# Resizing a table view to have two columns when in landscape

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa, uicollectionview

The App Store's Top Charts section, for example, shows a table or collection view that mimics the style of a UITableView. When the device is portrait it looks like a normal UITableView, but when the device (iPhone 6/7 Plus or iPad) is landscape it converts to two columns, but still mimics the overall style of a UITableView.

[image: App Store Landscape Orientation]
At the present moment I have a collection view set up that will adjust the size according to the orientation of the device. I have a border set at 1 pixel, but that makes borders double up where cells touch. Is there a better method?

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Is the problem with the borders the only aspect of your solution you find objectionable? What have you tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is the question about the cell border becoming prominent when selected ? If so please state clearly. Try using UICollectionViewDelegate to handle selection.